# Best way to concatenate multiple strings?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a project, where user can put in drop-down values that can be selected. One can select multiple values at a time. So, we have to store the selection and get it on edit mode.

### First thought

Let's store them as comma separated in DB.

f.e.
If suggestions are A , B , C and user selects A and B, I was going to store A,B in DB and while getting back the value split it with comma.

Problem arises when user has genuine "comma" in the field, for an instance **first,option** & **second,option**. At that time joining with comma won't work.

### Second thought

I can think of another option to store it in a stringified array format and parse it while getting back.

For the above instance, it would store the data as ["first,option","second,option"]. It seems to be a good (and only) option for me.

Even though I have a bit of hesitation doing so (which lead me questioning here!) because my users can access the api/DB value directly and for them it doesn't look good.

So, Is there any other way to address this issue to benefit both parties, developers and users? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What about Tab?

Comment: Don't store them in the same field in the database.

Comment: use pipes, this is my go to separator |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using a standardized format such as JSON, XML etc.

Serialize and parse and with a widely used library so all escaping of reserved / special characters is done for you. Rolling your own here will cause you problems!

Better yet, use different fields for each suggestion, this is a better design in general. As long as the number of potential fields is finite this will work, e.g. 1-10 suggestions.

If you're going down the JSON route, we can do this in JavaScript like this:

```
let suggestions = ['Choice A, commas are not, a problem, though punctuation is.', 'Choice B', 'Choice C'];
let json = JSON.stringify(suggestions);

// Save to DB
saveToDB(json);


let jsonFromDB = loadFromDB();

let deserializedSuggestions = JSON.parse(jsonFromDB);
console.log(deserializedSuggestions);
```

Answer (score 0):

**we use semicolon (;)** for this exact use case in our current project.

So, as per your question, they will be stored in the DB as `option1;option2;option3`

and when we get it back from the DB we can use the `split()` method on it to convert it into an array of substrings.

```
var str = "option1;option2;option3";
var res = str.split(";");
console.log(res);
```

which would result in `(3) ["option1", "option2", "option3"]` in the console.

hope this helps.